# How to use std::unordered_multiset with a custom class?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to declare an unordered_multiset which is going to contain objects of a custom class, but I can't find any examples out there for this. Following the documentation, it seems that I need to declare an `operator==` in the class, alongside the hashing function(`operator() const`) which, as per the documentation:

1. Accepts a single parameter of type `Key`.
2. Returns a value of type `std::size_t` that represents the hash value of the parameter.
3. Does not throw exceptions when called.
4. For two parameters k1 and k2 that are equal, `std::hash<Key>()(k1) == std::hash<Key>()(k2)`.
5. For two different parameters k1 and k2 that are not equal, the probability that
   `std::hash<Key>()(k1) == std::hash<Key>()(k2)` should be very small, approaching `1.0/std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()`.

The code looks like this in a very simplistic way:

**Class MyClass:**

```
// comparator
bool MyClass::operator ==(const MyClass b) const {                                                                          
    return (string == b.getString()); // compares two strings
}

// hash operation
size_t MyClass::operator()() const {                                                                         
    return hash<string>()(string); // bases the hash on the string
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
unordered_multiset<MyClass> s1;
// Also tried: unordered_multiset<MyClass, std::hash<MyClass>, std::equal_to<MyClass>> s1;
```

However, in the instatiation of the `unordered_multiset` the compiler (GCC) will complain about the hash functions (Tupla is the name of MyClass, and there are 1000+ lines, I included a few of them):

```
 error: use of deleted function ‘std::unordered_multiset<_Value, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::unordered_multiset() [with _Value = Tupla; _Hash = std::hash<Tupla>; _Pred = std::equal_to<Tupla>; _Alloc = std::allocator<Tupla>]’
   78 |     unordered_multiset<Tupla> s1;
      |                               ^~


/usr/include/c++/10/bits/unordered_set.h:949:7: note: ‘std::unordered_multiset<_Value, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::unordered_multiset() [with _Value = Tupla; _Hash = std::hash<Tupla>; _Pred = std::equal_to<Tupla>; _Alloc = std::allocator<Tupla>]’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
  949 |       unordered_multiset() = default;


/usr/include/c++/10/bits/unordered_set.h:949:7: error: use of deleted function ‘std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::_Hashtable() [with _Key = Tupla; _Value = Tupla; _Alloc = std::allocator<Tupla>; _ExtractKey = std::__detail::_Identity; _Equal = std::equal_to<Tupla>; _H1 = std::hash<Tupla>; _H2 = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing; _Hash = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash; _RehashPolicy = std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy; _Traits = std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, true, false>]’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/unordered_set:46,


/usr/include/c++/10/bits/hashtable.h:451:7: note: ‘std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::_Hashtable() [with _Key = Tupla; _Value = Tupla; _Alloc = std::allocator<Tupla>; _ExtractKey = std::__detail::_Identity; _Equal = std::equal_to<Tupla>; _H1 = std::hash<Tupla>; _H2 = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing; _Hash = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash; _RehashPolicy = std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy; _Traits = std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, true, false>]’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
  451 |       _Hashtable() = default;
```

An allocator is also mentioned as a pre-requisite for the unordered_multiset, but I neither understand it not I am sure whether that should be included (or how).

What did I miss?

Comment: please include a [mcve] of your code in the question

Comment: from where did you get that `MyClass::operator()()` is used for the hash? (you correctly quote that it is `std::hash<Key>()(k1)`) Or is this a typo here and `MyClass::operator()()` is actually `std::hash<MyClass>::operator()()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can replace string with your struct i guess:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

// Custom Hash Functor that will compute the hash on the
// passed string objects length
struct StringHashBySize {
public:
    size_t operator()(const std::string & str) const {
        int size = str.length();
        return std::hash<int>()(size);
    }
};
// Custom comparator that compares the string objects by length
struct StringEqualBySize {
public:
    bool operator()(const std::string & str1, const std::string & str2) const {
        if (str1.length() == str2.length())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
};

int main() {
    // Declaring unordered_multiset with Custom Hash Function and comparator
    unordered_multiset<std::string, StringHashBySize, StringEqualBySize> multiset;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That worked (using the class of course), thank you very much! I will mark your answer as accepted since it was the "first" one although, @fabian's answer is also valid (I guess that's the protocol in these situations?)

Comment: glad if I helped you ^^

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of doing this would probably be a helper class for the hash implementation:

```
struct MyClassHash
{
    const std::hash<std::string> m_stringHash {};

    size_t operator()(const MyClass& value) const
    {
        return m_stringHash(value.getString());
    };
};
```

and use this for hashing:

```
std::unordered_multiset<MyClass, MyClassHash> s1;
```

I btw recommend passing the parameter as reference to `operator==`, not by copy:

```
bool operator==(const MyClass& other) const;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I marked Devi khos's answer as accepted since it was earlier but yours is perfectly valid and useful too (Also, noted about the reference passing, I had missed that...)